# Difficulty understanding DEX logic

Tags: polkadot, pallet, substrate-node-template

Difficulty understanding DEX logic . in first I have to share the [Repository](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-dex) that I check the codes .

I could not understand this function. why should I implement the `create_exchange` function? what are the   `asset_id` , `liquidity_token_id`,`currency_amount`,`token_amount` . I want to know what are these arguments and also how can o fill them in the UI.

[image]

```
pub fn create_exchange(
        origin: OriginFor<T>,
        asset_id: AssetIdOf<T>,
        liquidity_token_id: AssetIdOf<T>,
        currency_amount: BalanceOf<T>,
        token_amount: AssetBalanceOf<T>,
    ) -> DispatchResult {
        // -------------------------- Validation part --------------------------
        let caller = ensure_signed(origin)?;
        ensure!(currency_amount >= T::MinDeposit::get(), Error::<T>::CurrencyAmountTooLow);
        ensure!(token_amount > Zero::zero(), Error::<T>::TokenAmountIsZero);
        if T::Assets::total_issuance(asset_id.clone()).is_zero() {
            Err(Error::<T>::AssetNotFound)?
        }
        if <Exchanges<T>>::contains_key(asset_id.clone()) {
            Err(Error::<T>::ExchangeAlreadyExists)?
        }

        // ----------------------- Create liquidity token ----------------------
        T::AssetRegistry::create(
            liquidity_token_id.clone(),
            T::pallet_account(),
            false,
            <AssetBalanceOf<T>>::one(),
        )
        .map_err(|_| Error::<T>::TokenIdTaken)?;

        // -------------------------- Update storage ---------------------------
        let exchange = Exchange {
            asset_id: asset_id.clone(),
            currency_reserve: <BalanceOf<T>>::zero(),
            token_reserve: <AssetBalanceOf<T>>::zero(),
            liquidity_token_id: liquidity_token_id.clone(),
        };
        let liquidity_minted = T::currency_to_asset(currency_amount);
        Self::do_add_liquidity(
            exchange,
            currency_amount,
            token_amount,
            liquidity_minted,
            caller,
        )?;

        // ---------------------------- Emit event -----------------------------
        Self::deposit_event(Event::ExchangeCreated(asset_id, liquidity_token_id));
        Ok(())
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This function creates a new exchange. This pallet is a implementation of the Uniswap V1 protocol, you can read more information about it [here](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v1/overview).

To create the exchange you need to deposit a initial liquidity: the `currency_amount` and the id of the asset `asset_id`.
It creates a new liquidity token (or using an existing one) `liquidity_token_id`, with a `token_amount` as the Initial amount of tokens to deposit in the pool. And then it mint & transfer to the caller account an amount of the liquidity token equal to `currency_amount`.

The description of this fields from the pallet [description](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-dex#parameters):

> - origin – Origin for the call. Must be signed.
> - asset_id – ID of the asset traded on the created exchange. Asset with this ID must exist.
> - liquidity_token_id – ID of the liquidity token to be created. Asset with this ID must not exist.
> - currency_amount – Initial amount of the currency to deposit in the pool. Must be at least equal MinDeposit.
> - token_amount – Initial amount of tokens to deposit in the pool. Must be greater than 0.

If you want to see an example of how to call the functions, check the test from the pallet: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-dex/blob/master/src/tests.rs#L10.

Comment: thanks for answer me but still i have a problem with that . you mean i have to create base token for my dex . for exmaple DDD token . and user has to buy for exmaple 100 of DDD token and user has to fill asset_id address which account has the DDD token . also user has to create a token by name UUU and put the owner address into liquidity_token_id . after that in this function : https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-dex/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L977 , transfer currency_amount of UUU token to pallet address ni this line https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-dex/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L993

Comment: also in this line we have currency_reserve and token_reservev , what are that ? https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-dex/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L1001

Comment: Is it curecct? .

Comment: Yes, when you are adding liquidity into a exchange you have to deposit the value of both token. The lines of code currency_reserve and token_reserve what does is reserve some balance into the exchange.

Comment: In Uniswap v1 docs you can see a more extend explanation about what add liquidity in a exchange means: https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v1/guides/pool-liquidity